# Custom post type with custom parent prefix slug

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

So for example, I have multiple custom post types **movies**, **games**, and **music**, I'd like to add a custom parent slug, so the output would be like this; or the custom post type slug should be the prefix slug of it,

- **sampledomain.com/movies/the-avengers** // (single-movies.php)
- **sampledomain.com/games/uncharted-4** // (single-games.php)
- **sampledomain.com/music/party-in-the-usa** // (single-music.php)

and lastly the default post url/permalink would be

- **sampledomain.com/articles/sample-article-post** // (single-post.php)

Is there a plugin that can help us do this? or better yet a code or sample / documentation that I can read about to make this feature happen?

Comment: This is the default behaviour for custom post types. If you want to add a prefix for regular posts you can add it by editing your permalinks format in _Settings > Permalinks_.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I see, the reason why it is not working for me it's because something added on my permalink, so that's the default behaviour of custom posts type, now i get it, thanks!

Comment: @JacobPeattie one last thing, If I tried to add a prefix to my regular post, it will be also applied to the custom post types, how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Set `with_front` in `rewrite` to `false` when registering the post type: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite

Comment: Hi Read this articles about wordpress themplate hierarchy https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

My was a mistake, I realize later that-- that is the custom post types default behavior, the reason it is not working for me because something is added to my Settings -> Permalinks that adds another prefix so the permalink of my posts is /articles/%postname%/ so the output is **/movies/sample-post**

I just removed the **/articles/** and selected Post-name in the radio button and it works now for me.